# Output .txt file with single max value of two vectors

Tags: r, write.table

Looking to output the number of unique id and time periods for each id into a .txt file.

Right now I have:

```
#Store N and T_Max (ie. Maximum number of periods per individual)
library(plyr)
mydata$id <- as.numeric(as.factor(mydata$ncountry))
N_max <- max(mydata$id)
mydata$count<-do.call(c, lapply(unique(mydata$id), function(curf){
seq(sum(mydata$id==curf))
}))
T_max <- max(mydata$count)
mydata$T_max <- rep(T_max,nrow(mydata)) # make new column 
mydata$N_max <- rep(N_max,nrow(mydata)) # make new column 
myvars1 <- c("T_max","N_max")
unique(myvars1)
newdata1 <- mydata[myvars1]
write.table(newdata1, "NT_input.txt", col.names=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, sep=" ")
```

Which gives the following style of .txt file:

```
194 15
194 15
194 15
194 15
.
.
.
```

I would only like a single row of output, ie:

```
194 15
```

Any advice is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Any reproducible example is welcome.

Comment: dplyr has `n_distinct`. data.table has `uniqueN`. I don't think this question should be tagged with `data.table`, though... seems unrelated to the content of the question

Comment: why not just use T_max and N_max, w/o rep?

Comment: I get an error w/o the rep. says there is an unexpected ',' in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't put the unique data, you may try this out
`uniquedata = unique(myvars1)
   newdata1 <- mydata[uniquedata]`

and now you can

`write.table(newdata1, "NT_input.txt", col.names=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, sep=" ")`

this should work

Comment: Tried using the code, still not working. Do I need to remove any of my previous code?

Comment: Disregard the comment above, code worked perfectly! thank you!